# Choose different images in one View with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

We have the following view:

[image: 4 different images with 4 different buttons to take a picture or select one from t]

All code is running well but when I finally select a picture , the photo is placed just in one ImageView. It should works like this:
We click each button below the UIImageView and it puts the selected picture in his ImageView.

My problem now is that all buttons are placing the photo in the first UIImageView.

How to place 4 different photos?

```
class selectorDeFotosViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

    //Outlets        
    @IBOutlet weak var fotoUno: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var fotoDos: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var fotoTres: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var fotoCuatro: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }

    //Actions       
    @IBAction func CamaraUno(sender: AnyObject) {            
        let alertPictureFrom = UIAlertController(title: "De dónde sacar la foto?", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

        presentViewController(alertPictureFrom, animated: true, completion: nil)

        alertPictureFrom.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 350.0, y: 458.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        alertPictureFrom.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

        alertPictureFrom.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cámara", style: .Default, handler: {action in

            let picker = UIImagePickerController()

            picker.sourceType = .Camera
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.allowsEditing = true

            self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }))

        alertPictureFrom.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Galería", style: .Default, handler: {action in

            let picker = UIImagePickerController()

            picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.allowsEditing = true

            self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))
    }

    @IBAction func camaraDos(sender: AnyObject) {

        let alertPictureFrom = UIAlertController(title: "De dónde sacar la foto?", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

        presentViewController(alertPictureFrom, animated: true, completion: nil)

        alertPictureFrom.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 350.0, y: 458.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        alertPictureFrom.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

        alertPictureFrom.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cámara", style: .Default, handler: {action in

            let picker = UIImagePickerController()

            picker.sourceType = .Camera
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.allowsEditing = true

            self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }))

        alertPictureFrom.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Galería", style: .Default, handler: {action in

            let picker = UIImagePickerController()

            picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.allowsEditing = true

            self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))
    }

    @IBAction func camaraTres(sender: AnyObject) {

        let alertPictureFrom = UIAlertController(title: "De dónde sacar la foto?", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

        presentViewController(alertPictureFrom, animated: true, completion: nil)

        alertPictureFrom.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 350.0, y: 458.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        alertPictureFrom.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

        alertPictureFrom.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cámara", style: .Default, handler: {action in

            let picker = UIImagePickerController()

            picker.sourceType = .Camera
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.allowsEditing = true

            self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }))

        alertPictureFrom.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Galería", style: .Default, handler: {action in

            let picker = UIImagePickerController()

            picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.allowsEditing = true

            self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))
    }

    @IBAction func camaraCuatro(sender: AnyObject) {


        let alertPictureFrom = UIAlertController(title: "De dónde sacar la foto?", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

        presentViewController(alertPictureFrom, animated: true, completion: nil)

        alertPictureFrom.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 350.0, y: 458.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        alertPictureFrom.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

        alertPictureFrom.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cámara", style: .Default, handler: {action in

            let picker = UIImagePickerController()

            picker.sourceType = .Camera
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.allowsEditing = true

            self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }))

        alertPictureFrom.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Galería", style: .Default, handler: {action in

            let picker = UIImagePickerController()

            picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.allowsEditing = true

            self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }))



    }


    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

        fotoUno.image = image



        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: what is fotoUno ? Is it a property of one image view or 4 image views?

Comment: fotoUno is the Outlet of the top left UIImageView Mr.T

Comment: \ Are you asking how to select multiple images on camera picker ?

Comment: are u going to present the camera picker 4 times, to select the 4 images , and each time you select an image, it will be placed into diff image view ?

Comment: In this line fotoUno.image = image you set selected image to first view; this is the reason.

Comment: Yes guys, we need to present the camera picker 4 times, to select 4 different images.

I know the wrong line is this: 

fotoUno.image = image


But how to show 4 different images?

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks Leo. I've used this project that you shared a time ago and it works perfect in yours but when I write the same code to mine it doesn't work.

Comment: I have updated the project. Try downloading it again

Comment: You need to select your button in Xcode UI and change the tag number to 1, 2, 3 or 4

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks Leo, now it's working perfect

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this.

1. You press button1, and set a BOOL value buttonOne to YES, and you present the picker, you select the image, and to display the image, you simply check is button is selected or not in the method `didFinishPickingImage`,so:

   ```
         if(buttonOne)
          {  
                 //set the image view 1 image
          }
   ```

You do the same for all the four image views:

```
             if(buttonOne)
           {  
                  //set the image view 1 image
           }
            if(buttonTwo)
           {  
                  //set the image view 2 image
           } if(buttonThree)
           {  
                  //set the image view 3 image
           } if(buttonFour)
           {  
                  //set the image view 4 image
           }
```

Make sure you set the other 3 bool values to NO, when you set one value to YES.

Comment: Ok thanks Mr.T . This actually display an error:

  if CamaraUno  {
            
            fotoUno.image = image
        }

Comment: The same when I try this: 

if CamaraUno == true  {
            
            fotoUno.image = image
        }

Comment: what kind of error ?

Comment: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type AnyObject -> () and bool

Comment: you don't need to do == true, you can simply do if(camaraUno)

Comment: make sure you declare all the 4 bool variables in your class, and you use them in the code.

Comment: Then I have the next error : Type (AnyObject) -> () does not conform to protocol Booleantype

Comment: I've tried conecting buttons like outlets too due to the previous errors.

I wrote this but it doesnt' work

 if (BotonUnoOutet != nil) {
            
            fotoUno.image = image
        }
        
        if (botonDosOutlet != nil) {
            
            fotoDos.image = image
            
            
        }

Comment: you didn't get my point. Did you declare the bool variables ?

Comment: var imagePicked = 0    Like this Mr.T